# Data binding for multiple languages

Tags: android, arrays, data-binding, multiple-languages

I have an android application, with 2 supported languages (greek & english). I have my string.xml for each language and they work correctly. My problem is that I have a Viewpager which gets its items from arrays like:

```
rank = new String[] { "one", "two", "three", "four"};
```

after binding, following this tutorial http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-viewpager-gallery-images-and-texts-tutorial/.
I tried to do something like this, into my Viewpage_activity:

```
if(Locale.getDefault().toString()=="el_GR")
{
   rank = new String[] { "ένα", "δύο", "τρία"};
}
else
{
   rank = new String[] { "one", "two", "three"};
}
```

But it doesn't work. Which is the best way to do data binding, when you have multiple languages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply create that array in both string.xml where `rank` is the name of the array in both xml files

```
<string-array name="rank">
    <item>One</item>
    <item>Two</item>
    <item>Three</item>
</string-array>
```

and in greek strings

```
<string-array name="rank">
    <item>ένα</item>
    <item>δύο</item>
    <item>τρία</item>
</string-array>
```

then use the array in your java code like :

```
String[] rank = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.rank);
```

hope it's what you're looking for :)

Comment: even better, in your data binding expression, you can use `@stringArray/rank` to access the string array.